# Linux dualboot not working well on Lenovo Laptop (Manjaro, Ubuntu, Pop OS)

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, manjaro, laptop, pop-os

I have been trying to download and run linux on my lenovo yoga slim 7i pro in dual boot since last week by now but I cant get rid of constant issues with it for some reason. I have tried Manjaro, Ubuntu and most recently Pop OS. In Manjaro the screen flickered and glitches out in the middle section whenever i moved the mouse and keyboard was not responsive, in both ubuntu and pop os too both issues remained.

I used ventoy to boot using a pendrive with official iso of the OS and have made a 100 GB partition in my ssd for the same. Secure boot is already off too. Windows 11 is preinstalled in the rest partition of the laptop ssd.

I have tried asking in Manjaro room in element and some people I know on discord who use linux on a daily basis, but to no avail. I also asked on reddit from where I got link to here. Any help in fixing and figuring out the problem is appreciated. Thanks for your time in advance. I have also tried out newer versions of fedora, ubuntu which fixed the dead keyboard issue, but not the screen glitch and flicker. I have also tried to switch from X11 to Wayland but to no avail again.

Hardware info - i5 11320H, 16 gb lpddr4x ram, 512 gb nvme ssd, 2880 x 1800 screen (16:10 ratio), Intel Iris Xe Graphics, 61 watt battery.

Comment: just to be clear, you CAN boot into linux (dual boot, whatever) - the issue is with screen flicker when you are successfully booted into Linux? So, the issue is likely to do with drivers for *Intel Iris Xe Graphics*

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to get into the OS, Which means you are able to "Dualboot" the problem here is with graphics, Go through [Intel Iris Xe](https://dgpu-docs.intel.com/devices/iris-xe-max-graphics/index.html) docs and [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309561/ubuntu-20-10-how-to-use-iris-driver-with-intel-iris-xe-graphics) on how to setup graphic driver.

Comment: I just gave it a few trials that but it hasnt fixed it yet. Do i need to install POP os onto my laptop first instead of using pendrive for this to work?

Comment: I tried what the link told me again and it says gedit function isnt supported and stuff in response to entering those commands.